# Emscripten wasmTable null when calling addFunction

Tags: reactjs, emscripten

I'm trying to get an older Emscripten project running in React and am having a runtime issue when I try to call addFunction. The stack trace looks like:

```
core.js:1981 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'grow')
    at getEmptyTableSlot (core.js:1981:1)
    at Object.addFunction (core.js:2013:1)
    at CoreBridge (CoreBridge.js:42:1)
```

The exception in getEmptyTableSlot is a null wasmTable when calling grow(1):

```
  var getEmptyTableSlot = () => {
      // Reuse a free index if there is one, otherwise grow.
      if (freeTableIndexes.length) {
        return freeTableIndexes.pop();
      }
      // Grow the table
      try {
        wasmTable.grow(1);
```

I've tried running it with and without a wasm file (using -sWASM=0 or 1), both cases fail at the same place. For the -sWASM=1 case, I'm pretty sure the .wasm file is getting loaded correctly because I remove the .wasm file from the server and get a different error indicating a load problem. I've also tried lots of options in the make file with no joy. The current set of link flags look like:

```
LDFLAGS =   --js-library platformDefinitions.js                                 \
            --post-js post.js                                                   \
            -s NO_DYNAMIC_EXECUTION=1                                           \
            -s RESERVED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=6                                     \
            -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=cwrap,addFunction,wasmTable             \
            -s ALLOW_TABLE_GROWTH                                               \
            -s ENVIRONMENT=web                                                  \
            -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='[                                            \
                "_SCB_SDKInit",                                                 \
                "_SCB_SDKFinal",                                                \
                "_SCB_registerReceivedAPIResponseCallback",                     \
                "_SCB_unregisterReceivedAPIResponseCallback",                   \
                "_SCB_registerReceivedSistrCallback",                           \
                "_SCB_unregisterReceivedSistrCallback",                         \
                "_SCB_registerAPICommandFailedCallback",                        \
                "_SCB_unregisterAPICommandFailedCallback",                      \
                "_SCB_sendSistr",                                               \
                "_SCB_sendAPICommand",                                          \
                "_SCB_freeOutData",                                             \
                "_SCB_createToy",                                               \
                "_SCB_destroyToy",                                              \
                "_SCB_createObject",                                            \
                "_SCB_destroyObject"                                            \
            ]'
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that things are initialized asynchronously and `addFunction` was being called before initialization was complete.  [Emscripten FAQ](https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/FAQ.html#how-can-i-tell-when-the-page-is-fully-loaded-and-it-is-safe-to-call-compiled-functions)

```
createMyModule(/* optional default settings */).then(function(Module) {
// this is reached when everything is ready, and you can call methods on Module
```

});